# Insert formatted content from HTML in Quill editor on load

Tags: javascript, html, editor, quill

I want to use Quill for writing articles on my website, however I may need to edit those articles at some point.

To retrieve my formatted content from Quill and put it into the database, I call ***quill.root.innerHTML***, and everything goes well.

**However**, I'm struggling to find how I could **get this HTML content**, and then **have it displayed in my Quill editor, formatted exactly as it was when I submitted it, when the page loads**.

Any help would be welcome, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Quill's contents are described by the JSON [`Delta`](https://quilljs.com/docs/delta/) format, and the API provides methods to [`getContents`](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#getcontents) and [`setContents`](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#setcontents) using this format:

```js
// Retrieve JSON using the Quill API
const delta = quill.getContents()
const ops = delta.ops;
// Store the JSON representation instead of the raw HTML
storeInDB(ops);
```

Then you can retrieve the JSON and it should all "just work":

```js
const ops = fetchFromDB();
quill.setContents(ops);
```